# How to make a text field box appear after clicking select option by using ajax?

Tags: ajax

I created a content type with a select field whose options are the following ones.

1. Text
2. Text area
3. File

When I select *Text area* (*text), a text area box (a text box) should appear below the select field. When I select *File*, a button should appear after the select field.

I heard this can be done using AJAX, but I don't know where to start and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module, which allows you to show/hide fields based on other field's values.

From the module description:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> A simple use case would be defining a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked, but much more complex options are available.